# graphing issues in glmer with predicted probabilities and prediction bands

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I have a model that I ran in glmer, which is below:

```
multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag <- glmer(allbuster ~ lageutradeshare100 + lagtradeopenP  + colonial  
                                    + lagtradesharePT + lnlaggdpp + lnlaggdpt  + duration + lndist + nobust + nobustsq + nobustcb + (1 | partnercode) + (1 | caseid),
                                      data=sanctions.data.new.scaled, family=binomial(link="logit"),
                              nAGQ=1,control=glmerControl(optimizer="nlminbwrap",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

Data can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nem4kxu7ydyc0p9/testdata.csv?dl=0).

I've figured out, using the `predict`command in R how to get the predicted probabilities, using the code below. As far as I can tell the predicted probabilities are correct:

```
tmpdat_intraeu <- multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag@frame[, c("caseid", "lndist", "lnlaggdpt", "duration",
"partnercode", "lnlaggdpp", "lagtradeopenP", 
"lageutradeshare100", "lagtradesharePT", "nobust", "nobustsq", 
"nobustcb", "colonial")]

jvalues_intraeu <- with(multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag, seq(from = 
min(multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag@frame[["lageutradeshare100"]]), 
to = max(multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag@frame[["lageutradeshare100"]]), 
length.out = 100))

pp_intraeu <- lapply(jvalues_intraeu, function(j) {
  tmpdat_intraeu$lageutradeshare100 <- j
  predict(multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag, newdata = tmpdat_intraeu, type = "response", re.form = NA)
})

# I don't think that the lines below this point are working for me; this is where I think the problem is:

plotdat_intraeu <- t(sapply(pp_intraeu, function(x) {
    c(M = mean(x), Med = median(x), quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE), (mean(x)-(2*sd(x))),
      (mean(x)+(2*sd(x))))
}))

plotdat_intraeu <- as.data.frame(cbind(plotdat_intraeu, jvalues_intraeu))
colnames(plotdat_intraeu) <- c("PredictedProbabilityMean", "PredProbMedian", "quartile1", "quartile3", "lowersd", "uppersd", "lageutradeshare100")
head(plotdat_intraeu)
tail(plotdat_intraeu)

sb_intraeu <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=plotdat_intraeu, aes(x = lageutradeshare100, y = PredictedProbabilityMean), size = 2, color="blue") + 
  geom_ribbon(data=plotdat_intraeu, aes(x = lageutradeshare100, ymin = lowersd, ymax = uppersd),
              fill = "grey50", alpha=.5) +
  ylim(c(-.5, 1)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
    geom_rug(data=subset(multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag@frame,allbuster==0), aes(x=lageutradeshare100), color="black", size=1.0, sides="b", alpha= 3/4, length = unit(0.05, "npc")) +
    geom_rug(data=subset(multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag@frame,allbuster==1), aes(x=lageutradeshare100), color="red", size=1.0, sides="b", alpha = 1) +  
 theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dotted"), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"), axis.title.x = element_text(size=12, face="bold")) +
  xlab("Intra-EU Trade Share") + 
  ylab("Predicted Probability of Sanctions Busting") 

sb_intraeu
```

My problem is that the resulting figure gives me something like this:
[image]
In sending my paper for review to my committee, one of the faculty members told me that the confidence intervals are not calculating correctly and are far too wide. I agree with the assessment, and I have seen that it is difficult to confidence intervals in these types of models, but I am at a loss to understand how I can "fix" the graph. I have seen suggestions for bootstrapping using `predictInterval` and `bootMER```, but i haven't been able to figure out how to make them work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My paper is largely written, but I can't submit it until I have better visualizations of the effects of my key IV.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been using the merTools package which may help.  A tutorial on how the package is used can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/merToolsIntro.html).

One of the things this package does well is that it allows you to specify which types of randomness you want to be accounted for in the confidence intervals that it reports.  I would write more about that here, but the tutorial explains it better than I could so I would reccomend just reading the "Uncertainty" section of the tutorial.